# Does realloc keep the memory alignment of posix_memalign?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix

Aligned `malloc` is `posix_memalign`, that's OK, but what about the aligned `realloc`? Does `realloc` retain the alignment or how to assure that reallocated memory has the same alignment? Assume Linux and x86_64.

Comment: Nope - if you need a particular alignment e.g. for SIMD data, then don't use realloc.

Comment: So, if I do need "aligned realloc", I must free and posix_memalign new memory, right?

Comment: Yes - you could even implement your own `posix_memrealloc` like this if you really wanted to.

Comment: "I must free and posix_memalign new memory, right?" - no, why not just implement the logic yourself: it's just a bit of padding, rounding and an offset - then you can call realloc.... Also, several of your questions are tagged C++ but really have nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @Tony: It's not that simple, "when padding" you waste memory, something like 1/2 at the worst case.

Comment: @Tony: you *could* call realloc, but if the new buffer is at a different alignment from the old one then you'd have to `memmove` everything and adjust your offset.

Comment: @James: true, but it's quite possible that posix_memalign implementations will be layered over malloc such that they're equally inefficient.  Even if not, the real memory usage of such small allocations may be significantly more than the application-requested size given overheads for free lists etc., again effectively reducing the 1/2 figure.

Comment: @Steve: true, and could be a deal breaker depending on the performance needs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, `realloc` on the memory returned from `posix_memalign` is not guaranteed by either ISO or POSIX to maintain the same alignment. A `realloc` *may* simply expand the current block at the same address but it may also move the block to a different address whose alignment is less strict than the original.

If you want the same alignment, it's probably best to allocate another block and copy the data over.

There is, unfortunately, no `posix_memalign_realloc` function in the Single UNIX Specification either.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of copying data *every* time, you could try the `realloc` <sup>(a)</sup> and, if the alignment of that was not as expected, *then and only then* call `posix_memalign` to get a correctly aligned address and copy the data in to there, freeing the old address when done.

This may result in:

- zero copies (if the current block can be expanded in-place);
- one copy (if `realloc` copies but happens to give you a correctly aligned block); or
- two copies (if `realloc` copies and then you also have to copy due to misalignment).

It *may* also result in less copying than indicated depending on the underlying memory management implementation. For example, a "copy" may simply involve remapping memory blocks rather than physically moving the data.

So you may want to keep some statistics to see if this scheme is worthwhile.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Just keep in mind that neither POSIX nor Linux man pages specify whether or not you even *can* pass these pointers to `realloc`, only that you can pass them to `free`.

However, based on the current GNU libc source code, it appears to work, although that's no guarantee it will continue to work in future :-)

My fear was that it would allocate memory normally (standard alignment) and pass back an offset address (ie, not the actual address allocated, but one `N` bytes beyond that) which `free` was intelligent enough to turn back into the actual address before weaving its magic.

One way of doing that would be to store the *actual* address immediately before the returned address though this of course would lead to wastage even for regular allocations.

In that case, `free` may have been made intelligent (since the specs say it must be able to handle the allocations done by `posix_memalign`) but `realloc` may not have been given the same intelligence (since the docs are silent on that matter).

However, based on GNU glibc 2.14.1, it actually allocates more memory than needed then fiddles with the arena to free up the pre-space and post-space, so that the address returned is a "real" address, usable by `free` or `realloc`.

But, as stated, the documentation doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: This answer is not correct in one important way: realloc usually does not copy even if the memory area moves. I think that if there isn't enough room at the current memory address to expand a buffer - the pages are remapped to avoid a copy. So its would be zero copies, zero copies, one copy.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista, you are confusing some *implementations* with the *standards.* There is *nothing* in the standards (ISO/POSIX) which mandates how things happen under the covers. However, it appears that the question was changed after my answer to assume Linux which narrows the field somewhat (but less than you may think since Linux runs on a huge variety of hardware with possibly wildly varying MMU options). Will adjust the answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the glibc source code for realloc, it calls directly on to malloc. So the memory is aligned in the same way as malloc.

Comment: Sorry, I should add. In the source, if there is additional heap space in the location already pointed to by the original malloc'd memory then it just allocates additional heap at the end of the original allocation size without calling malloc. This obviously won't change the alignment.

Comment: posix_memalign() is called in place of malloc; and makes guarantees that malloc doesn't.    The question isn't about malloc + realloc, it is about posix_memalign and realloc.