# What's the reallocation equivalent of std::aligned_alloc()?

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment, dynamic-allocation, memory-reallocation

I've noticed [`std::aligned_alloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) coming into C++17, and I like it. But - what happens when I need to reallocate? I can do this manually (assuming the available space at the currently-allocated address is just the amount of space I asked for), but shouldn't there be a facility for this in the standard library?

Comment: After a bit of searching, I could not find anything in the standard library for explicit reallocation, but c++17 does have an `std::align()` function that would make writing your own `realloc()` not too difficult (not that it would be too difficult anyway). The link for that is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align

Comment: Related, if not essentially a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314602/does-realloc-of-memory-allocated-by-c11-aligned-alloc-keep-the-alignment

Comment: @Alerra: The problem is, that as a user, I don't know how much more space is available, so I have to be over-conservative; while the system libraries, or the kernel, do know; so I would allocate more often than I should...

Comment: That's a good point. I was searching through SO and happened on your other question regarding this (it is a very valid question), but yeah it definitely is odd that c++ doesn't have and standard library `realloc()`'s that support alignment that I know about. Maybe in a future version?

Comment: I'm not sure if they will give you a `std::aligned_realloc()` because if you can't expand the current buffer you need to get a new one, copy everything over, and then free the old buffer.  This isn't trivial if you have non trivial types.  Essentially it would be rebuilding `vector`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: These functions work on `void*`'s...

Comment: @einpoklum: Define "work". If any object in the storage to be realloced has a pointer to any object within that same storage, then the object will be broken. And that is not based on the *type* of the object, but on its current *value*.

Comment: If you want to use realloc, so you are looking for efficiency. If you are looking for efficiency => go directly to system calls and create your own allocator. Take a look at glibc malloc implementation. This uses assumptions about hardware that are 20 years outdated. I just can bet that the same is true on MSVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't such standard call equivalent.

Even more so, Microsoft's latest implementation of C++ still has its own `_aligned_malloc()` instead of the now standardized `std::aligned_alloc()`, and [here they explain why](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/11/c17-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-2017-15-3/):

> aligned_alloc() will probably never be implemented, as C11 specified
>   it in a way that’s incompatible with our implementation (namely, that
>   free() must be able to handle highly aligned allocations).

Among their (Microsoft's) underscore-prefixed implementations they do serve you with [`_aligned_realloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-realloc) :-)