# type-punning with std::aligned_alloc for array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, c++17, type-punning

There is already a lot of posts about strict aliasing rule and type-punning but I couldn't find an explanation that I could understand regarding array of objects.
My goal is to have a memory pool non-template class that is used to store arrays of objects.
Basically I need to know the actual type only at access time: it can be seen as a non template vector whose iterators would be template.
The design I thought of rises several questions so I will try to split them into several SO questions.

My question (which is the third one, see below) is merely how to implement the `DefaultAllocate()` function in C++17 with `std::aligned_alloc` (and without `std::align_storage` which is doomed to deprecation).

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// type that support initialisation from a single double value
using test_t = float;

// just for the sake of the example: p points to at least a sequence of 3 test_t
void load(test_t* p) {
    std::cout << "starting load\n";
    p[0] = static_cast<test_t>(3.14);
    p[1] = static_cast<test_t>(31.4);
    p[2] = static_cast<test_t>(314.);
    std::cout << "ending load\n";
}

// type-punning buffer
// holds a non-typed buffer (actually a char*) that can be used to store any
// types, according to user needs
struct Buffer {
    // buffer address
    char* p = nullptr;
    // number of stored elements
    size_t n = 0;
    // buffer size in bytes
    size_t s = 0;
    // allocates a char buffer large enough for N object of type T and
    // default-construct them
    // calling it on a previously allocated buffer without adequate call to
    // Deallocate is UB
    template <typename T>
    T* DefaultAllocate(const size_t N) {
        size_t RequiredSize =
            sizeof(std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>) * N;
        n = N;
        T* tmp;
        if (s < RequiredSize) {
            if (p) {
                delete[] p;
            }
            s = RequiredSize;
            std::cout << "Requiring " << RequiredSize << " bytes of storage\n";
            p = new char[s];
            // placement array default construction
            tmp = new (p) T[N];
            // T* tmp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
            // // optional for arithmetic types and also for trivially
            // destructible
            // // types when we don't care about default values
            // for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            //     new (tmp + i) T();
            // }
        } else {
            // placement array default construction
            tmp = new (p) T[N];
            // T* tmp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
            // // optional for arithmetic types and also for trivially
            // destructible
            // // types when we don't care about default values
            // for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            //     new (tmp + i) T();
            // }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    // deallocate objects in buffer but not the buffer itself
    template <typename T>
    void Deallocate() {
        T* tmp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
        // Delete elements in reverse order of creation
        // optional for default destructible types
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            tmp[n - 1 - i].~T();
        }
        n = 0;
    }
    ~Buffer() {
        if (p) {
            delete[] p;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t N = 3;
    Buffer B;
    test_t* fb = B.DefaultAllocate<test_t>(N);
    load(fb);
    std::cout << fb[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << fb[1] << '\n';
    std::cout << fb[2] << '\n';
    std::cout << alignof(test_t) << '\t' << sizeof(test_t) << '\n';
    B.Deallocate<test_t>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/beanfW1MK)
[Live more complex](https://godbolt.org/z/cM3M5Esq6)

[link to question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946075/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing-rule-for-array-of-objects)
[link to question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946115/type-punning-omitting-placement-new-and-destructors)

[EDIT] [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947531/21691539) to this question shows that my C++14 snippet above might not be properly aligned: [here is](https://godbolt.org/z/M4fPPxK7x) a proposed better version inspired from the referenced answer.
see also [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946075/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing-rule-for-array-of-objects) for some additional material.

Comment: "_The third one_": You should mention that this is the question you are asking in _this_ one. (The same applies to your other questions.)

Comment: `aligned_alloc` is not supposed to be deprecated(contrary to `aligned_storage`). Just pass in the alignment (as first argument) and size - both in bytes. The result is aligned. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to implement the `DefaultAllocate()` function in C++17 with `std::aligned_alloc`

- First, I'd make sure that the allocator actually releases memory when it goes out of scope. For that, I'd use a `std::function<void()>` in which you can store the loop calling the destructors for elements stored in the `Buffer`. This has the benefit that you don't need to know the type when you later want to deallocate. It's stored in the functor.
- When checking if we need to allocate new memory we need to ...

  - check if the currently allocated memory is aligned according to `alignof(T)`. If it's not, `std::free` the old memory and call `std::aligned_alloc`.
  - check if the the previously allocated memory is large enough. If it's not, use `aligned_realloc` (see Note below) to acquire more.

It could look like this:

```cpp
// holds a non-typed buffer (actually a void*) that can be used to store any
// types, according to user needs
struct Buffer {
    // destructing functor storage
    std::function<void()> destructors = [] {};
    // buffer address
    void* p = nullptr;
    // number of stored elements
    size_t n = 0;
    // buffer size in bytes
    size_t s = 0;
    // allocates a buffer large enough for N objects of type T and
    // default-construct them calling it on a previously allocated buffer
    // without adequate call to Deallocate is **OK**.
    template <typename T>
    T* DefaultAllocate(const size_t N) {
        destructors(); // call destructors since it may already be occupied
        size_t RequiredSize = N * sizeof(T);
        n = N;
        T* tmp;
        if(!p || reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p) % alignof(T) != 0) {
            // first allocation or incorrect alignment
            std::free(p);
            p = std::aligned_alloc(alignof(T), RequiredSize);
            if(p == nullptr) return nullptr;
            s = RequiredSize;
        } else if (s < RequiredSize) {
            // not enough room
            auto re = aligned_realloc(p, alignof(T), RequiredSize); // See note
            if(re == nullptr) return nullptr;
            p = re;
            s = RequiredSize;
        }
        // placement array default construction
        tmp = new (p) T[N];

        // create destructor functor
        destructors = [this] {
            T* tmp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
            // Delete elements in reverse order of creation
            while (n > 0) {
                tmp[--n].~T();
            }
        };
        return tmp;
    }
    // deallocate objects in buffer but not the buffer itself
    void Deallocate() { destructors(); }

    ~Buffer() {
        destructors();
        std::free(p);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dxYP311Wf) - which uses `std::realloc` (which has undefined behavior since the memory wasn't allocated with `std::malloc`, `std::calloc` or `std::realloc`). It's a conceptual demo, not a plug-and-play solution.

**Note:** `aligned_realloc` doesn't currently exist in the standard library and implementations differ when it comes to the support for doing aligned reallocation. MSVC has `_aligned_realloc` which requires `_aligned_free` and also `_aligned_alloc` instead of `std::aligned_alloc`. POSIX has [`posix_memalign`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, it shows that my c++14 version is incorrect because it is misaligned.
I will update my questions snippet accordingly

Comment: perhaps I have validated the answer a bit lightly: in the realloc case, you may lose alignment, may you not?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876847/whats-the-reallocation-equivalent-of-stdaligned-alloc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884745/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-of-aligned-realloc for instance.
IMHO it's a bit strange...

Comment: @Oersted _"in the realloc case, you may lose alignment"_ - Yes, I had that thought too when going to bed and I tried it out this morning. In the quick test, gcc lost alignment while clang did not - but it was a one shot test so perhaps clang will too. I think an `aligned_realloc` is needed and I made a quick version of it but haven't had the time to update the answer. I will do that when I get back from work (~6 hours).

Comment: FYI, the second link in comment propose an aligned_realloc which try a simple realooc, test aligment, and in case of failure deallocate and allocate again with proper alignment and size.

Comment: @Oersted Yes, I had something similar in mind. Alt., keep two pointers. One aligned and one to the raw storage. That requires overallocation to work though, so perhsps not. Will think...

Comment: I just thought about another solution: allocate one extra-element in size and compute the smallest offset from start in order to get a valid address in terms of alignment. Just store the offset for the sake of the ```Destructors``` functor. *Et voila*

Comment: a possible [quick and dirty implem](https://godbolt.org/z/z9zr8sW48) of a well-behaved reallocation

Comment: @Oersted _"allocate one extra-element"_ - That's the overallocation I was thinking of. You'd then need to keep two pointers. One to the raw storage that you use with `free` and when calculating the proper alignment for the type - and one that points to the aligned offset from the raw storage pointer. I just had a quick look at your impl. and it looks like what I had in mind, yes :-) Perhaps I should just replace `std::realloc` with `aligned_realloc` and a note, leaving it up to whomever is reading this answer to make the implementation. In MSVC, `_aligned_realloc` can be used etc.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your original comment.

Comment: @Oersted No worries. Instead of providing a full fledged solution for `aligned_realloc` I added some notes.  The portable and easy solution is of course to not even try to `realloc` but to `free` and `malloc` if `s < RequiredSize`. At least as a first step.

Comment: @Oersted It should have been _"to `free` and `aligned_alloc`"_ above of course.  A sidenote: I'm comparing what cppreference says about the core C functions and what the C23 draft says about some of the new functions. Sometimes cppreference says the opposite of what the standard says so now I'm editing on cppreference a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

> [H]ow to implement the `DefaultAllocate()` function in C++17 with `std::aligned_alloc` (and without `std::align_storage` which is doomed to deprecation)[?]

You can *ask* the compiler, no Standard Library trait actually needed ;)

```
template<class T>
struct RequiredSize
{
    alignas(alignof(T)) unsigned char data[sizeof(T)];
};


struct Buffer {
    // ...

    template <typename T>
    T* DefaultAllocate(const size_t N) {
        size_t RequiredSize = sizeof(RequiredSize<T>) * N;
        // ...
    }
};
```