# What options do I have if I want to realloc memory and use 32 (or 64) byte alignment?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm writing some SIMD code. I'll need my arrays to be aligned to 32bytes with an option to upgrade to 64byte if I ever decide to target a CPU that supports 512bit simd instructions.

From what I can tell realloc doesn't seem to keep any promises about the alignment. It seems malloc and realloc will only guarantee 8bytes/64bits?

Without writing my own what are my options if I want to reallocate a piece of memory?

Comment: Does [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) work?

Comment: @Eljay: The `alignas` specifier only applies to variable declarations, but the OP is asking about dynamic memory allocation using `malloc`/`realloc`. Therefore, it will not work.

Comment: It appears that you need to use the function [`aligned_malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc). However, the linked documentation does not state whether the alignment is guaranteed to be preserved by [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: If you are using the Microsoft Windows platform, you can use [`_aligned_realloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-realloc).

Comment: Related question: [Is there really no version of realloc() supporting alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503469/is-there-really-no-version-of-realloc-supporting-alignment)?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) which can be used to acquire a pointer to an aligned region of memory. You can check whether the reallocated region is still aligned by comparing the pointer with the result of `std::align`. If not, a `memmove()` might be neccessary.

There is also [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) which might be an option for aligned allocations of a fixed (i.e compile-time) legnth.

---

A possible implementation strategy could be an allocator which retrieves memory from a specific memory pool. The memory pool only returns memory aligned by `std::align` or could manage blocks of `std::aligned_storage`. This approach also gives you all the advantages of memory pools, e.g cache locality, no memory fragmentation and perhaps faster allocation algorithms (depends on your pools implementation and that of `malloc`).